# Why is a mount of a remote samba share read only?

Tags: samba, share

I have successfully mounted a samba share (from a Centos server) on my Raspberry Pi, but the share is read-only:
`sudo mount -t cifs //ip.address/sharename /mnt/test -o user=username,vers=1.0`

I have also (with it unmounted) issued chmod 666 /mnt/test as I found reports that resolved the issue.

I can access the share read/write from Windows machines and linux machines. In fact, using the Raspberry Pi's File manager and putting smb://ip.adddress/sharename in the address bar, I can write to the folder without having it mounted.

I have tried shares on more than one machine and they all mount as read-only.

What have I missed in mounting the share that causes it to be read-only?

(most questions are about why a Raspberry Pi share is read-only. To be clear my issue is not with shares on the Raspberry Pi but accessing shares on other computers).

[Edit]
This is the smb.conf on the server that I am trying to connect to:

```
[User]
        comment = User Files
        valid users = peter,powerpete,admin
        write list = peter,powerpete,admin
        path = /mnt/md0/shares/user/
```

Comment: What is the content of the smb.conf file?  My guess is that guests are allowed but the named user in the mount is not detailed or been added to the samba users database.

Comment: [User]
        comment = User Files
        valid users = peter,powerpete,admin
        write list = peter,powerpete,admin
        path = /mnt/md0/shares/user/

peter is the username I am connecting with. (Obviously there are carriage returns in there only they don't survive - I'll also add the extract on my post)

Comment: Did you add the users into the Samba user list using smbpassword?  If so, did you give them a password? If so that's missing from your mount line...

Comment: My server has the correct user (my Windows PC has no problem connecting). In my samba mount, it was user=peter. The mount then asks for the password (which I entered).

Comment: Sorry - did you add the user to smbpasswd with a password or not?  (last comment spell corrected)...  The issue maybe you are using sudo and user try *-o username=user,password=pwd*

Comment: Yes the user does have a password - without that on the mount, it asks for the password when return is pressed, which I then obviously enter.

Comment: Try mounting the share in a folder under the users home folder.  If that works try changing the /mnt security as well as all folders in the path of the mount.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this will help you

```
cat /etc/samba/smbd.conf on my server:


[media]
path = /home/pi/shared/data/media
read only = no
public = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

then mounting script on my raspberry machine:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mount -t cifs -o uid=1000,gid=1000,user=pi,pass=`cat /home/pi/samba.cred` //server-IP-or-name/media /home/pi/shared/data/media
```

then the mounted share is fully read/write on raspberry
on other machines - i.e. my Macbook - it works without even asking for user/password - just mount as Guest
I have no Windows to check it

Comment: This looks like you are sharing files FROM a RPi to other machines, not connecting from a RPi to another server as I am trying to do.

Comment: from rpi1 to rpi2